# Flutter - anyone have a Flow example to conditionally wrap with left and right align?

Tags: dart, flutter

Newbie question...

Looking at Flutter docs, looks like Flow will solve a problem.

Unfortunately, there is no example provided (or available by searching on the date of this question) and it is giving some trouble in implementing correctly.

Here's how I'd like two elements to behave, similar to CSS float left and float right.

When there's sufficient screen width, make two things adjacent

```
-------------------------------
| THINGHERE   BIGGERTHINGHERE |
-------------------------------
```

When there's not sufficient screen width, stack with top left aligned, bottom right aligned

```
--------------------------
| THINGHERE              |
|        BIGGERTHINGHERE |
--------------------------
```

I'm currently using Wrap with calculated widths on the elements, but it seems like Flow would do this more gracefully.

Anyone have an example that achieves this use case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Flow` is *not* for such case. `Wrap` is the only thing you want.

The main reason is because `Flow` size **can't** depend on it's children size. Which means it's impossible to use it to achieve what you asked for.

If you need a more complex layout, you can instead create your own `RenderBox`. As `RenderBox` can get much more complicated layout logic.